# Find duplicates with a where clause

Tags: mysql

mysql table structure
meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value 
(WordPress posmeta table)

I want to find all duplicated rows in the meta_value table - but only where meta_key = _customer_user

I know how to find duplicates easily enough - but I can't figure out a way to filter them for just meta_key = _customer_user

Any ideas?

Comment: show some sample data. it will easy to give ans

Comment: hey @knowledge.... sure thing - this is what the table looks like https://i.imgur.com/PeSVkrQ.png

Comment: what is the duplicate here ?

Comment: @knowledge.... that screenshot shows the dataset already filtered with a simple WHERE `meta_key` = '_customer_user' clause. There are other values in the meta_key table. I'm only interested in rows where meta_key = _customer_user

Comment: @knowledge.... the duplicate is the meta_value value - so in the dataset in the screenshot, the value "2" is the customer - you can see there are 5 rows with the meta_value "2"

Comment: then simple add group by meta_value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139784/discussion-between-knowledge-and-ed-bloom).

Answer (score 0):

```
    select group_concat(meta_id) from TableName where meta_key ='_customer_user'
        having meta_id <> min(meta_id)
group by meta_value
```

it will give you all meta id where is duplicate. it will not include first insert id.

Comment: gives me an error "Unknown column 'meta_id' in 'having clause'"

Comment: @EdBloom can you try now ?

Comment: still throwing an error... You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where meta_id <> min(meta_id)' at line 3

Comment: @EdBloom if you got your solution you can write here as a ans

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where meta_id <> min(meta_id)
group by meta_value' at line 2

Comment: can you try now

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question you can try;

```
    SELECT  meta_key, meta_value 
    FROM 
    ( SELECT meta_key, meta_value, COUNT(*) AS RC
      FROM YOUR_TABLE
      WHERE meta_key='_customer_user'
      GROUP BY meta_key, meta_value ) A 
    WHERE RC>0
```

Or in a shorter form:

```
  SELECT meta_key, meta_value 
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
  WHERE meta_key='_customer_user'
  GROUP BY  meta_key, meta_value 
  HAVING COUNT(*) >0
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion - but this throws the following error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value 
    FROM 
    ( SELECT meta_id, p' at line 4"

Comment: I apologize (error with past and copy): I'm going to correct it now

Comment: thanks for the update - so this gives me back the full set of records - https://i.imgur.com/heqhdUh.png - what I really want is something like "meta_key, meta_value, count" or a real sample: "_customer_user, 1, 6"

Comment: btw - my real sample is based on the screenshot where you can see there are 6 rows where _customer_user = 1